# How can I validate an XML doc which has ampersands inside any of elements without getting an exception?

Tags: xml, perl, validation

I have a non-editable XML file which has a few unwanted tags placed in between, so I get an exception when I validate the XML document using XML::Simple. This is expected.

```
my $xml = new XML::Simple(); 
if (eval { $xml->parse("sample.xml") }) {
    print "success!!\n";
} else {
    print "failed!!!\n";
}
```

However, the parser is also throwing exceptions for ampersands inside a URL in the XML doc. The expected result is that ampersands inside the body of the XML shouldn't cause an error to be thrown. How can I overcome this using XML::Simple or any other XML parser module? I tried XML::Simple, XML::LibXML and XML::Mini::Document. None of them succeeded with the ampersand issue.

Comment: Re "*How can i successfully validate an xml which have ampersand inside any of the xml tag*", That's not allowed (unless the ampersand is part of a defined entity), so it sounds like everything is working correctly.

Comment: In addition to your problems with using an XML parser to parse a document that isn't well-formed XML, you are giving yourself another problem by using XML::Simple. In the [documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Simple), the modules author says "PLEASE DO NOT USE THIS MODULE IN NEW CODE" and "The use of this module in new code is strongly discouraged". Please don't ignore his advice.

Answer (score 2):

The correct terminology for what you are doing is checking to see if the document is [*well-formed*](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-well-formed) (matches the definition of an XML document), not if it's [*valid*](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-prolog-dtd) (matches the definition of an XML document and the definition of a schema). You can use [XML::LibXML::Schema](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/XML-LibXML/lib/XML/LibXML/Schema.pod) to validate documents.

That said, it sounds like your check is working correctly. What you are providing isn't (well-formed) XML, and the parser is telling you that.

---

This isn't (well-formed) XML:

```
<ele url="http://www.example.org/form?foo=bar&moo=mar"/>
```

It should be

```
<ele url="http://www.example.org/form?foo=bar&amp;moo=mar"/>
```

---

This isn't (well-formed) XML:

```
<ele>http://www.example.org/form?foo=bar&moo=mar</ele>
```

It should be

```
<ele>http://www.example.org/form?foo=bar&amp;moo=mar</ele>
```

Comment: Ok, so there is no Perl XML module using which i can use by implicitly tell to ignore if ampersand is encountered.

Comment: Such a parser would be buggy.

Comment: It would be buggy if it were marketed as an XML parser. If it were marketed as a tool for repairing ill-formed XML, that would be a different matter...

Comment: @Michael Kay, 1) The OP asked for an XML parser/validator. 2) The OP didn't for anything to be repaired. 3) How would such a tool repair `&foo`? It is a missing semicolon or an unescaped `&`?

Comment: (1) They asked "how can I" without constraining the solution, (2) Writing repair tools is a completely different art from writing parsers. The answer is, you make guesses, and then it's a question of how intelligent to make your guess. For example, you could take into account whether an entity named foo actually exists. But the key message is, while you can recover a lot of corrupt data this way, it's better to insist on getting clean data in the first place rather than having to repair a mess.

Comment: @Michael Kay, Re "*They asked "how can I" without constraining the solution,*", No. Again, they clearly asked how to validate, not how to perform modifications. Furthermore, they specifically said changes are not allowed. /// Re "*Writing repair tools*", huh, you were talking about using existing tools earlier, and you just made my point by pointing out it would need to be a custom solution. StackOverflow is NOT a code writing service, so this idea of yours is off-topic. /// Please cease your off-topic comments.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have an XML file. The parser is telling you that it's not an XML file. If you want to use non-XML files, don't try to process them using XML tools.

If the originator of the file claimed that it was XML, tell them they have sent you a faulty file and ask for it to be fixed, or switch to a more reliable supplier. (What would you do if you downloaded a program claiming to be Java and it didn't compile?)

Comment: The file which i get in a clearcase vob is of .xml extension, inside the file there is a tag description with text as <description>https/blahblah.blah.com/isynch.dll?panel=ModuleConfig&Type=ModuleView&Module</description>.  Is there any way i can comprehend this??

Comment: I don't know what a "clearcase vob" is, but despite its file extension, it is not XML, and it's about as much use to you as a car with comfy seats, four wheels, shiny trim on the headlights, and no starter motor. Send it back and complain.

Comment: @MichaelKay: ClearCase is a version control system and VOB is "Versioned Object Base" which is the mechanism it uses for storing version information.

Answer (score 2):

You may be able [XML::Liberal](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Liberal), which will happily take this kind of broken XML. It may also break your XML is other ways, so buyer beware!

Since it is a subclass of XML::LibXML you could use it instead of XML::LibXML, but I would not do that. I would instead have a first pass where you convert your quasi-XML to proper XML (and you can check it), and then use regular XML tools for the rest of your processing (probably not XML::Simple though, see the warning in the docs of the module).

The converter could be as simple as:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Liberal;

my $parser = XML::Liberal->new('LibXML');
my $doc = $parser->parse_file( 'broken_xml.xml');

print $doc->toString;
```

Realize that this is a dangerous solution, using a module that is in alpha state and has not been touched in 6 years. So it definitely cannot be used as part of a production system.

The real solution is to get the input to be real (well-formed) XML. Which is possible, the naked `&` in URLs can be replaced either by `&amp;` or by `;`, but you should use HTML tools for this, not XML ones. Or shame your provider into sending you real XML.

In the meantime, XML::Liberal may be part of a temporary solution.

Comment: Re "*The naked `&` in URLs can be replaced either by `&amp;` or by `;`*, 1) You can't arbitrarily replace `&` in URLs with `;`. CGI.pm (and others) consider them the same, but that's neither standard nor universal, even if you assume that all queries are form data. 2) It's possible that replacing `&` with `&amp;` isn't the correct repair either (e.g. `&foo` could have been a typo for `&foo;`), so even that isn't guaranteed to be a correct fix either.incorrect fixes.

Answer (score 1):

> I have a non-editable XML file

Actually, no. You don't have an XML file. You have something that is almost, but not quite, an XML file. A well-formed XML document does not contain ampersands other than ones that make the start of an entity (which these ones aren't). An ampersand in a well-formed XML documented should be encoded as `&amp;`.

I guess you have three options:

1. Go back to the source of this "not-XML" document and ask them to send you something that is well-formed XML. If this comes from an external supplier, there may well be contracts in place saying that they will supply you with XML. If so, they are breach of contract.
2. Pre-parse the document to correct the encoding of the ampersands. This is likely to be fragile and I don't recommend it.
3. Use something like XML::Liberal to parse the document. I don't recommend this as once you allow non-standard XML, it's a slippery slope that leads to the mess that we saw in HTML parsers in the 1990s :-)

If it was down to me, I would definitely take the first option.

Comment: Yes Dave you are correct, i have this XML file (rather would call it as a file with .xml extension :) ) inside a clear case vob where i do not have checkout/checkin  access. Thanks for your comments.

Comment: @Kalesh: So you need to trace the file to its source. Where did it come from? Who created it? Someone will have the ability to fix this for you. You just need to work out who.